# Uso excessivo de canetas c#

Tags: c#, desempenho, gráfico, drawing

Bom dia amigos,

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que deve desenhar 4 gráficos (por enquanto), para desenhar da maneira pretendida preciso redesenhar os gráficos várias vezes e atualizá-los. Com uso excessivo da caneta ("drawline") cai muito o desempenho. Quando eu paro de desenhar, todo meu app roda normal, mas quando ele começa a desenhar tudo vai ficando lento ate travar completamente(inclusive os botões). Por favor, alguém sabe uma forma de otimizar esse código? Alguma dica? Muito obrigado!! Segue abaixo as principais partes do código.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //metodo que chama o controle que desenha o gráfico---------------------------------------
    private void SerialCOM_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (SerialCOM.IsOpen)
        {
            SerialPort sData = (SerialPort)sender;
            {
                string RxString = sData.ReadLine();
                bool result = int.TryParse(RxString, out int data);
                if (result)
                {
                    var atualdata = 5.0f * data / 1023.0f;

                    //CHAMADA DO CONTROLE
                    graphControl1.AddValue(atualdata, atualdata, atualdata, atualdata);

                    if (controlegravar == 1 && aquisicaodata.Count <= 6000) aquisicaodata.Add(atualdata);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
//CONTROLE------------------------------------------------------------------------

public class GraphControl : Control
{

    public void AddValue(float value1,float value2,float value3,float value4)
    {
        _values1.Add(value1);
        _values2.Add(value2);
        _values3.Add(value3);
        _values4.Add(value4);
        Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        var wid = (float)Width / (float)_dataCount;
        var total = 5;

        //-----------------------------------------1--------------------------------------------------------------------

        var lastPoint1 = new PointF(0F, (float)(2*Height/5) * 0.5F);
        var lastPoint2 = new PointF(0F, (float)(Height / 2));
        var lastPoint3 = new PointF(0F, (float)(7 * Height / 10));
        var lastPoint4 = new PointF(0F, (float)(9 * Height / 10));
        PointF newPoint1 = new PointF();
        PointF newPoint2 = new PointF();
        PointF newPoint3 = new PointF();
        PointF newPoint4 = new PointF();

        var idInit = _values1.Count - _dataCount;

        if (idInit < 0)
            idInit = 0;

        for (int i = idInit, a = 0; i < _values1.Count; i++, a++)
        {
            var value = (float)(_values1[i]);
            var porcent = value / total;

            if (porcent > 1) porcent = 1 ;
            var hg = porcent * (2*Height/5);

            newPoint1.X = (a + 1) * wid;

            if (porcent >= 1) newPoint1.Y = 2*Height/5 - hg;
            else newPoint1.Y = 2*Height/5 - hg - 1;

            using (var p = new Pen(Color.Lime, 0.1f)) e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, lastPoint1, newPoint1);

            lastPoint1 = newPoint1;

            //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            value = (float)(_values2[i]);
            porcent = value / total;

            hg = porcent * (Height / 5);

            newPoint2.X = (a + 1) * wid;

            newPoint2.Y = 3 * Height / 5 - hg;

            using (var p = new Pen(Color.Lime, 0.1f)) e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, lastPoint2, newPoint2);

            lastPoint2 = newPoint2;

            //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            value = (float)(_values3[i]);
            porcent = value / total;

            hg = porcent * (Height / 5);

            newPoint3.X = (a + 1) * wid;

            newPoint3.Y = 4 * Height / 5 - hg;

            using (var p = new Pen(Color.Lime, 0.1f)) e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, lastPoint3, newPoint3);

            lastPoint3 = newPoint3;

            //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            value = (float)(_values4[i]);
            porcent = value / total;

            hg = porcent * (Height / 5);

            newPoint4.X = (a + 1) * wid;

            newPoint4.Y = Height - hg;

            using (var p = new Pen(Color.Lime, 0.1f)) e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, lastPoint4, newPoint4);

            lastPoint4 = newPoint4;
        }

        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
}
```

Detalhe: o método datareceived é chamado por um timer com um intervalo de 3 ms. Precisa ser muito rápido.

Comment: Felipe, voce ta usando o que ? Web, Windows ?

Comment: O código é extenso para uma analise mais apurada. O que você pode fazer é diminuir ou eliminar todos os casts implícitos e explícitos do código. Você precisará fazer um estudo de depuração do código e entender onde estão os gargalos.
Uma dica por onde começar é aqui: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/?view=vs-2017 Para a aplicação não travar enquanto desenha pense na possibilidade de trabalhar com Threads ou Async/Await. Não temos uma noção completa da sua ferramenta para poder opinar mas vale a pena estudar isso. Sobre Threads: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1490

Comment: Não tem como avaliar só com esse trecho de código sem conhecer o contexto como um todo... Qual é o intervalo em que o onPaint é chamado?

Comment: Thiago, Estou usando Windows.

Comment: Leandro, vou dar uma editada aqui.

Comment: Vou dar uma estudada nos links, obrigado!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma taxa de atualizacao de 3ms é maior que a taxa de atualização da tela tanto em 60fps (16.6ms) ou 120fps (8ms). Mesmo que você force o Invalidate a cada 3 ms, ele não atualizará ao mesmo tempo. Tente otimizar o datareceived para funcionar asyncronous e vê a possibilidade de ou aumentar o tempo de atualização ou deixar a chamada do Invalidate async.

Comment: boa tarde amigo, tentei usar async await no datareceived e o gráfico fica todo deformado. Você poderia me dar dicas de como eu posso deixar a chamada do invalidate async??

Comment: valeu pela atenção!

Comment: Quando eu torno o Invalidate() async, o gráfico se desenha travando tambem, porém o programa começa a rodar normalmente, os botões não travam.

Comment: Acho melhor não chamar o Invalidate a cada adicionada do valor pois como vc disse ele é muito rápido. tente fazer uma lógica para chamara o Invalidate após a 10a chamada do AddValue ou algo assim. Voce está forçando o grafico a ser desenhando, enquanto ele ainda está desenhando, por isso ele trava.

Comment: Deu certo, com 5 chamadas do AddValue antes do Invalidate(), o programa ja desbugou . Valeu cara!